# Web Scraping Using Selenium and Pandas

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, xpath, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

I am relatively new to web scraping and I am using Selenium Library with Pandas to scrape this website https://www.blackrock.com/corporate/insights/blackrock-investment-institute/interactive-charts/geopolitical-risk-dashboard#risk-summary. In the graph there is a drop down menu.

I am using this xpath to locate the dropdown menu: //div[@style='display: inline-table; width: 294px;' ]//select

When inspecting on browser it is working perfectly fine however when adding it into my code I am having NoSuchElement Exception.

Here is the code I am writing for this element:

```
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@style='display: inline-table; width: 294px;' ]//select"))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text('Emerging markets political crisis')
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved. The drop down menu is located in iframe so I had to switch the driver to iframe.

Here is the soution:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='flourish-1']"))
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@style='display: inline-table; width: 294px;']//select"))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text('Emerging markets political crisis')
```